# Gitlab CI: Rules for stages only if an artefact exists

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab CI for automation and I have a terraform plan that runs and stores the plan as an artefact for the apply stage.  If the plan says there are changes it creates a file artefact to show there were changes and this is to be used to enable/disable the apply stage such that it does not show up unless plan stage found changes.

I am of the belief from further reading that the rules are evaluated at the beginning of the pipeline so I don't believe rules is the answer.

This works on one CI pipeline but not another.  On the first it always creates the stage from the beginning but on the second it never creates the stage:

```
      when: manual
      rules:
        - if: $TF_DESTROY != "true" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" && $ENV == "prod"
          exists: 
            - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/terraform/environments/${ENV}/tf_plan_changes_found
```

As stated I do not believe rules to be the correct way and have now disabled the exists statements.

Is there another way I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. `rules:` are evaluated before the pipeline is formed. Artifacts obviously don't exist until a job produces/restores artifacts at run time. Therefore, for this and other reasons, `rules:changes:` can only operate on files that are committed to your repository.

The most reasonable thing to do might be to check for the existence of the artifact in the job.

```yaml
apply:
  script:
    - |
      if [[ -f "$STATE_FILE" ]]; then
          echo "applying $STATE_FILE"
      else
          exit 1
      fi 
      # ...
```

But generally, you should know what job produces the required artifact and you can setup an explicit dependency between the jobs using `dependencies:` or `needs:`